# MapBox NumberFormat expected syntax

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm struggling a lot with MapBox Studio

I need to format elevation and use the `numberFormat` function.

However, I didn't succeed to find the right syntax. The documentation is very poor.

So far I did try to do this:

```
number-format(elevation, {'locale':'fr'})
```

but it  keep says syntax is not correct. Tried double  quote, tried also to add.

I found this only information:

> Converts the input number into a string representation using the
> providing formatting rules. If set, the "code" argument specifies the
> locale to use, as a BCP 47 language tag. If set, the currency
> argument specifies an ISO 4217 code to use for currency-style
> formatting. If set, the min-fraction-digits and max-fraction-digits
> arguments specify the minimum and maximum number of fractional digits
> to include.

[image: Mapbox Studio attempt to use NumberFormat function]

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax to use seems to be documented there : https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/

For my need, the right way to do it was

```
[
'number-format',
['get', 'elevation'],
{ 'locale': 'fr' }
]
```